# Getting blank AJAX data from MediumEditor div

Tags: jquery, ajax, medium-editor

I originally had a `<textarea name="userWords">` that correctly triggered a jquery call and sent data. But I needed nicer text editing, so I'm trying to use [MediumEditor](https://github.com/yabwe/medium-editor) instead of the textarea. I have the following html:

```
<form method="post" action="/userWords" enctype="multipart/form-data"  data-id="{{uniqueId}}" id="{{uniqueId}}-userWords">
    <div name="userWords" id="ThisBox" class="editable" contenteditable="true"></div>
</form>
```

And the following AJAX used to work with `textarea` but now no longer works:

```
 var Id = $(this).data('id');
 var data = new FormData($("#" + Id + "-userWords")[0]);

        var ajaxOptions = {
            url: '/userWords',
            data: data,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(res) {
              //...do stuff
            }
        };

        $.ajax(ajaxOptions);
```

Basically, the data is null. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: tried using a json instead of that `FormData`?

Comment: https://github.com/yabwe/medium-editor/blob/master/API.md#mediumeditorelements-options

check here

Comment: you need both the div and the textarea according to the git doc

Comment: @BuddhiAbeyratne: I read that as "if you want to use `<textarea>` this is how MediumEditor handles it". I think you can just use `<div contenteditable="true">` in place of `<textarea>`.

Comment: happens a lot when you read long boring docs i guess :3

Comment: @BuddhiAbeyratne: Do you mind editing my code example to show how the json approach would work? I tried following an example, but get null data, just as before.

Comment: can you tell me the php keys you are listning to coming off of the text area ?

Comment: Actually, I am using Node.js to process the data. I use `req.body` which gives me references to the `name="userWords"` input (and any other `name`s I defined). `req.body` = [] for my `div`. But if I use `textarea`, everything is as expected. I can see the data is not being sent, so I assumed the error was on the JS side...

Comment: ok iv put a cod eup check it and if it doesnt work try nesting it
like 
`{idname:{"ThisBox": textdata}}` replace id name with `Id + "-userWords"`

Comment: Ok, just saw this. Will check this variation.

Comment: Still null... With no errors. So you think it's not finding the `name` element?

Comment: it works via php for me btw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
 var textdata = $('#'+ThisBox).val();
 var my_object = {"ThisBox": textdata};

        var ajaxOptions = {
            url: '/userWords',
            data: my_object,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(res) {
              //...do stuff
            }
        };

        $.ajax(ajaxOptions);
```

Comment: I made some small corrections and got this to work! I had to call with an 'id' tag rather than a name tag and I changed .value to .val(). I made some small edits in your answer to reflect this.

Comment: oh 
awesome 
nice to have helped you out :)
i was thinking of other ideas but failed so that's why i didn't put  any more answers upon your first comment.
any ways nice to have helped you